# Java Streams: Why can we pass non-static method references in map

Tags: java, java-stream

I was wondering why we can pass method references even for methods that do not match the expected signature. How does the JVM know that it should call the method of the instance passed, rather than calling the method with the passed instance as first parameter. Here is an example of what I mean:

```java
class Person {
    String name;
    
    public Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Person> listOfPeople = new ArrayList<>();
        listOfPeople.add(new Person("Mike"));
        listOfPeople.add(new Person("Tom"));

        // this makes perfect sense, since we pass a lambda with the signature Person -> String
        listOfPeople.stream().map(person -> person.getName()).forEach(System.out::println);
        // I know that this works but I don't understand why, the method passed has signature void -> String but java somehow knows to resolve it like on top.
        listOfPeople.stream().map(Person::getName).forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's one of the ways to write a lambda.  If you reference the type, Java assumes the first argument from the lambda is the instance to be used.  This is documented in the JLS [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No `void` figures here.**

Remember that `Person::getName` method reference of `Function` doesn't mean a transformation from `void` to `String` but `Person` to String`.

The `map` method requires a `Function<T, R>` where `T` is the original type (`Person` in your case) and `R` stands for the transformation result type, which can be anything.

Notice the method `public String getName()` has `String` as the return type which is inferred into `R` and the parameter of the `map` method becomes `Function<Person, String>` regardless whether it is written as `person -> person.getName()` or `Person::getName`. They both mean the same.

Again, there is *no* `void` figuring.

Comment: Ok. Thanks to your answer I understood how the JVM resolves the correct method. You can actually cause en error if you also define a method `public static String getName(Person p)` in class Person even though this is perfectly fine on compile time, trying to call `.map(Person::getName)` will crash due to ambiguous methods.